# Boolean Value Resets to True in Test Method

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, boolean

Trying to get code coverage up and I am not understanding why this boolean value will not pass from the test method to the class. It always returns true.

**Test Method**:

```
  @isTest static void test_searchmorePages() {
    Test.startTest();
    CustomerController controller = new CustomerController();
    controller.standardSearch = false;
    controller.searchAdditional();
    controller.standardSearch = false;  
    controller.next();
    controller.clear();
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

**Custom Controller:**

```
public class CustomerController {
    public boolean standardSearch{get;set;}

public void searchAdditional() {
standardSearch = false;
}

public void next(){
     if (standardSearch = true) {
        system.debug('its true');
     }

     else {
         system.debug('its false');
     }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if (standardSearch = true) {
```

You are performing an assignment with `=` inside this `if` statement. Use `==` to compare for equality.

As a guard against this kind of mistake, you can write the constant first:

```
if (true == standardSearch) {
```

Then you get an error if you write the wrong number of = signs.

sfdxfox rightly notes that simply referencing Booleans without a comparison in a truth context, as `if (standardSearch)` or `if (!standardSearch)` is in many ways a better idiom that avoids this issue entirely. You may in a few cases want to make the comparison explicit as above - if you might have a `null` value, certainly, or in highly complex logical expressions where the more verbose form is more readable or clear.

The `constant == variable` pattern is one that applies equally in other contexts where you're making such a comparison against an lvalue (an expression to which a value may be assigned). For example,

```
if ('foo' == myStringVariable) {

if (2 == myIntegerVariable) {

if (2.0 == mySobjectList[1].Some_Currency_Field__c) {
```

Comment: That moment you realize everything you've ever created with a boolean conditional is wrong.

Comment: My rule of thumb is to never compare a boolean to true or false: `if(standardSearch)` and `if(!standardSearch)` are the only form I use. I know people always say "but what about the nulls?!" to which I respond "My boolean values are never null. I initialize."